# How to buffer an HTTP response using the request module?

Tags: node.js, stream, request

I would like to stream the contents of an HTTP response to a variable. My goal is to get an image via `request()`, and store it in in MongoDB - but the image is always corrupted.

This is my code:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png', function (error, response, body) {
    image = new Buffer(body, 'binary');
    db.images.insert({ filename: 'google.png', imgData: image}, function (err) {
        // handle errors etc.
    });
})
```

What is the best way to use Buffer/streams in this case?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The request module buffers the response for you.  In the callback, `body` **is** a string (or [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)).

You only get a stream back from request if you don't provide a callback; `request()` *returns* a  [`Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html).

[See the docs for more detail and examples.](https://github.com/mikeal/request#super-simple-to-use)

---

request assumes that the response is text, so it tries to convert the response body into a sring (regardless of the MIME type).  This will corrupt binary data.  If you want to get the raw bytes, specify a `null` `encoding`.

```
request({url:'http://google.com/doodle.png', encoding:null}, function (error, response, body) {
    db.images.insert({ filename: 'google.png', imgData: body}, function (err) {

        // handle errors etc.

    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the calification. I have updated my question. Please see if you can expand your answer.

Comment: Wow. Thank You, it worked. That's been driving me nuts for so long.

Comment: thx this works, but I see that when passing 'encoding: null', in the callback, body is Buffer and not string. to me this is the primary reason why this works.

Answer (score 3):

```
var options = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Length': contentLength,
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    },
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/lottery/lt',
    body: formData,
    encoding: null, // make response body to Buffer.
    method: 'POST'
};
```

set encoding to null, return Buffer.

Comment: In my case the encoding: null resolved my issue. I was trying to send a pdf buffer which was the response from a serveless function that created the pdf buffer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried piping this?:

```
request.get('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(request.put('{your mongo path}'))
```

(Though not familiar enough with Mongo to know if it supports direct inserts of binary data like this, I know CouchDB and Riak do.)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use pipe. It's possible to stream directly into mongodb but that will mean I will have to use Gridfs which I want to avoid.

Comment: This is HTTP Rest, but you can pipe to a local file too:  https://github.com/mikeal/request#streaming

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you can easily retreive a file in binary with Node 8, RequestJS and async await. I used the following:

```
const buffer = await request.get(pdf.url, { encoding: null });
```

The response was a Buffer containing the bytes of the pdf. Much cleaner than big option objects and old skool callbacks.