# How to send image to client using Express/Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, google-places-api

I am writing a simple Express API integrating with Google Places API, and trying to send the place photo down to the client, but can't get it to work. The response from the Google Places API looks something like this:

[image]

The response object also contains a `headers` property. I've tried sending the image back like this:

```
 router.get('/photo/:photoRef', function (req, res) {

  var params = {
    maxwidth: 400,
    photoreference: req.params.photoRef,
    key: key
  };

  var url = baseUrl + 'photo?' + querystring.stringify(params);

  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      res.type(response.headers['content-type']);
      res.send(response.body);
    }
  });

});
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I get the following image:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set 'encoding' to null in request options. This has the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145533/how-to-buffer-an-http-response-using-the-request-module?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Set the response type to image/png.

```
res.set({'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
```

To save this data as an image in your client app refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376410/byte-array-into-an-image-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is response.body is a readable stream, you should use

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
response.body.pipe(res);
```

That will solve the problem.