# Byte array into an image Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, byte

I have a long array of bytes, with numbers from 0 to 255, and I know it's an image, so *how can I save it like a file?* I have tried a lot of things, but not success.
The image is created but won't open because it's damaged.

**File .js**

```
function saveImage(filename, data){
  //Data = [1,6,2,23,255,etc]
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(ARTWORK_PATH+filename);
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       wstream.write(data[i].toString('base64'));
   }
   wstream.end();
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're writing the data to a file as a base64 encoded string. You need to save it in binary format for it to be opened as an image file.

Answer (score 2):

Why use base64 encoding? If your image data in the data parameter as binary, you can write it.

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data,  "binary", function(){...});
```

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work, I also tried `data.join()` before writing it but nothing. The bytes array comes from this plugin [jsmediatags](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader), they have the next method to do it but does not work to me.

`var base64String = "";
for (var i = 0; i < image.data.length; i++) {
    base64String += String.fromCharCode(image.data[i]);
}
var dataUrl = "data:" + image.format + ";base64," + window.btoa(base64String);`

Comment: what is wrong? maybe you can indentify your saved image first bytes. for example when you save a png file, the first bytes contains "PNG" string which you can read

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it doing this!**

It was as simple as use a buffer...

```
function saveImage(filename, data){
  var myBuffer = new Buffer(data.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      myBuffer[i] = data[i];
  }
  fs.writeFile(ARTWORK_PATH+filename, myBuffer, function(err) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          console.log("The file was saved!");
      }
  });
}
saveImage("image.jpg", [0,43,255,etc]);
```

Comment: I tried this, the image is creating but when I am trying to open the image file, its saying that 'photo viewer doesn't support this file format '